# How to transfer my system to a new laptop harddrive?

Tags: installation, multi-boot, mirroring

So I bought a brand new 500GB SSD Hybrid drive for my laptop. I would like to start using it.

- How do I go about mirroring my current 200GB hardisk on to there in such a way that I can just swap out the harddrives and get going?

Bonus question: I am currently running Windows 7 and dual-booting to Ubuntu which is installed via wubi. Ideally I would like to be able to have both installed side-by-side on the new drive and dual boot regularly. What do I need to do for that? Super-ideally (though less important) I would like the ubuntu install to be exactly what I currently have via wubi so that I don't have to install apps/set up stuff all over again.

While a step-by-step would be awesome, mostly I just have no idea where to get started with this so I'm looking for a general idea of what I need to do, what tools I need, and how much time this will likely take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two drive bays in your laptop you can install both hard drives and clone one to the other.
Download and burn a [Clonezilla Live CD](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php), boot to it, clone your existing drive to the new one and then remove the old drive to test booting.  Clonezilla has a great beginner mode and prompts you through the whole process.

If you can't install both drives, you can put one in an external enclosure or use Clonezilla to copy your old drive as an image on an external drive and then restore the image to your new drive, though this will take longer.

[Here](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone)'s a guide for using Clonezilla to copy disk-to-disk.

Comment: You may need to expand the partition after you're done since the old drive is smaller than the new one.  You can do this with [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)